# Which Nginx server actually respond with image data?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have two servers with Nginx running on both.

On **first** server I'm enabling proxy_pass to *all* (png|jpg|gif)  and so on to **second** server.

So my question is - Which server actually respond with image data?

1) Second ->(bytes)-> First ->(bytes)-> Client
or
2) Second ->(bytes)-> Client

I have a serious restriction in traffic on my **first** server and want **second** server which has not this restrictions to respond with all images.

Can I do it like I do, or I need to actually use **second** server in all img tags?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use first server as a proxy between client and second server, then the answer of course is (1), the first server responds to client.